# How to Display Login if Not Logged in and Display Session name when logged in

Tags: php, html

When I enter this code it makes the page unusable. I have tried variations and yet it still doesn't work.

I am trying to make it display "Login" When you are not logged in and to display the username when logged in.

```
<?php
if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
} else {
echo "Login"
}
?>
```

If more is necessary please comment.

Section this code is in

```
<li class='active'><a>
<?php
if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
} else {
echo "Login";
}
?>
</a>
```

And these are the functions that initiate the code

```
function CheckLogin()
{
     if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }

     $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

     if(empty($_SESSION[$sessionvar]))
     {
        return false;
     }
     return true;
}

function UserFullName()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
}
```

Comment: Did you start the session?

Comment: Yes I have, I use this code to normally display a username <?=$fgmembersite->UserFullName();?> but I need it to not be this way any longer

Comment: Well, it's probably the missing semi-colon for `echo "Login"` unless that's a bad paste. Other than that, why are you using a "return"? Just echo it, unless you're doing that elsewhere. Your code checks out otherwise.

Comment: I'll let someone else take over then. Good luck.

Comment: add session_start(); on the second line and before where you set the $_SESSION["name_of_user"] in your other script.

Comment: Still shows "Login" Even when logged on.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon on line 7, should be:

```
echo "Login";
```

Comment: That fixed some but it isnt the main problem, once I do this is makes the word login appear but even while logged in it shows login. Once I logout the whole page except the navbar is broken.

Comment: Could you post some more of your code Devin, hard to see with just a few lines, thanks